# What causes this failure to use a middleware method in the routes file, in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app with users, roles and permissions. I use **Microsoft Azure** for user sign-in.

I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.

I get a list of *comma-separated user permissions* specific to every user role, from a `permissions` MySQL table.

I want the current user to have access to certain routes, depending on the *permissions* they have.

I store the `userPermissions` variable in a session like this:

```
public function storeTokens($accessToken, $user, $user_role, $user_permissions) {
    session([
      'accessToken' => $accessToken->getToken(),
      'refreshToken' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
      'tokenExpires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
      'userName' => $user->getDisplayName(),
      'firstName' => $user->getGivenName(),
      'lastName' => $user->getSurname(),
      'userRole' => $user_role,
      'userPermissions' => $user_permissions,
      'userEmail' => null !== $user->getMail() ? $user->getMail() : $user->getUserPrincipalName(),
      'userTimeZone' => $user->getMailboxSettings()->getTimeZone()
    ]);
}
```

I have created a new middleware, called `CheckUserPermissions`:

```
class CheckUserPermissions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    private $permission;

    // Permissions checker
    public function hasPermissionTo($permission) {
        return in_array($permission, session('userPermissions'));
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check user permissions
        if (!$this->hasPermissionTo($this->permission)) {
            return redirect('/')->with('error', 'You do not have permission to access to this section of the application');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I registered the above middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //More middleware
    'checkSignedIn' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSignedIn::class,
    'checkUserPermissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserPermissions::class,
];
```

#### The problem

The problem is that I am unable to use the policy/gate outside the controller (even though the current user *does* have the permission to view users).

Doing `Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index'])->middleware('checkUserPermissions')->hasPermissionTo('view-users')` in `routes\web.php` does not work:

```
// Dashboard routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardContoller::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index'])->middleware('checkUserPermissions')->hasPermissionTo('view-users');
});
```

It results in a `Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::hasPermissionTo does not exist` error being displayed in the browser

##### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access middleware methods in the route definitions. The middleware only runs the `handle` method so you should write your code with that in mind. Here's how you can solve this:

```
class CheckUserPermissions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    private $permission;

    // Permissions checker
    public function hasPermissionTo($permission) {
        return in_array($permission, session('userPermissions'));
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
    {
        // Check user permissions
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            if (!$this->hasPermissionTo($permission)) { 
               return redirect('/')->with('error', 'You do not have permission to access to this section of the application');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and use the middleware as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardContoller::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index'])->middleware('checkUserPermissions:view-users');
});
```

Anything after the `:` in the `checkUserPermissions:view-users` is sent as an additional argument of the `handle` method. You can also send multiple ones:

```
Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index'])->middleware('checkUserPermissions:view-users,see-users,glance-at-users');
```

each item in the comma separated list is an additional array entry in the `$permissions` array of the middleware